# Why is it not showing biggest integer?

Tags: python-3.x

Getting 4 numbers from user:

```
num1 = int(input("Types your numbers: "))
num2 = int(input("Types your numbers: "))
num3 = int(input("Types your numbers: "))
num4 = int(input("Types your numbers: "))
```

Converting them to list:

```
list=[num1,num2,num3,num4]
list.sort()
print(list)
```

If-else chain:

```
if list[0]>list[1]:
    print(num1)
elif list[1]>list[2]:
   print(num2)
elif list[2]>list[3]:
    print(num3)
elif list[3]>list[0]:
    print(num4)
```

I have entered 4 values and the second biggest number is printing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the use of the if-else chain after having sorted the list? Also note that after sorting, list[0] is not necessarily synonymous with num1 and the same goes for the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is although you are applying logic correctly but you are just printing the input variables (num1,num2 etc), you should use list[n] which contains largest number, here's the correct code:

```
if list[0]>list[1]:
    print(list[0])
elif list[1]>list[2]:
   print(list[1])
elif list[2]>list[3]:
    print(list[2])
elif list[3]>list[0]:
    print(list[3])
```

I would rather use this piece of code to get max. value:

```
inps = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(max(inps))
```